# Prevent writing different symbols into select2 input

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jquery-select2, sql-injection

I have default select:

```
<select id="indivCitizen" multiple="multiple">
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Which I replace with select2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#indivCitizen').select2({
        ajax: {
          url: "/countrylist",
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            var query = {
              search: params.term
            }
            console.log(params)
            return query;
          },
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data.items
            };
          }
        },
        placeholder: 'Write country name',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        maximumResultsForSearch: 1,
        tags: true,
        maximumSelectionLength: 1,
        language: {
          inputTooShort: function () {
            return 'Search will start after 3 symbols';
          },
          maximumSelected: function (e) {
            var t = "You can choose only one";
            return t
          },
        },
      });
    })
```

And it all connected with MSSQL DB, so I need to be secured from different injections

I tried this, but it worked only with default inputs:

```
document.getElementById("indivCitizen").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
      if (e.key.match(/[()`'"!@#$%^&*=_+,.*;:/|\\<>?~]/))
        return e.preventDefault();
    });

    document.getElementById("indivCitizen").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(
        /[()`'"!@#$%^&*=_+,.*;:/|\\<>?~]/g,
        ""
      );
    });
```

So I need to prevent writing different symbols into select2 input

Comment: Your `countrylist` end point needs to be secured against SQL injection, not the UI.

Comment: In any case, there will be a need for knowledge of preventing typing different symbols in select2

Comment: If you insist of false-security of removing characters before the ajax call then remove them in `data: function(params)` which is where it determines the `search` parameter, eg `var query = { search: params.term.replace(/\-/g, '') }` (or so)

Comment: that doesn't work correctly :( or maybe i just make it wrong:
`search: params.term.replace(/[()'"!@#$%^&*=_+,.*;:/|\\<>?~]/g, "")`

Comment: Well, if you're using a regex, you'd need to provide a valid regex.   Try with something small first, such as `/,/g`.  Then add other parts until it doesn't work. RegEx's have special characters that must be escaped, eg `-` -> `\-`.  Pretty much most of them TBH...

Answer (score 0):

To block special characters at the time of input (to improve the UX), you can add an a delegated event listener to

```
input.select2-search__field
```

Example (as tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery))

```
$(document).on("input", "input.select2-search__field", function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(
        /[()`'"!@#$%^&*=_+,.*;:/|\\<>?~]/g,
        ""
    ); 
});
```

Notes:

- this will affect *all* select2 inputs on the page
- this will provide the horrible UX of jumping to the end of the input if the cursor is not at the end, on every invalid keypress/input

But should get you closer to your end goal

Comment: :D seems like something really bad, but anyway need to find out how to prevent writing symbols into select2 input without any troubles

Comment: It's the usual `this.value = this.value.replace(` issue - there's a way around it by getting selectionState/selectionEnd and restoring it to reset the cursor position.  The key here is the `$(document).on("input", "input.select2-search__field", ` selector.